# configure site tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I need help on this problem I am facing.

> > I am trying to server a website [say www.mysite.com] from one of the dedicated server I have rented.
> >
> > I am using Apache tomcat 6.0.18. I am not using any webserver for this. Tomcat is serving as webserver as well.
> >
> > I have changed default port from 8080 to 9001.
> >
> > I have made DNS entry in host file of server [x.x.x.x pointing to www.mysite.com]
> >
> > When I build the project, mysite.war is created and on deploying it, 'mysite' folder is created within webapps [as per standard].
> >
> > I will serve only 1 site from my rented server.

Problem: When I try to access my website as www.mysite.com nothing happens and I get timeout error.

But when I access my website with url as www.mysite.com:9001/mysite/welcome.html , I get proper home page loaded on internet.

I think there seems some problem in my server.xml setup [or any other setup].

Someone kindly assist me with this setup issue.

Please let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Thanks, 
SF

Answer (score 1):

The http protocol defaults to port 80.

Either change your tomcat installation to use port 80 (from port 9001), or put a proxy in front of Tomcat (apache, nginx, varnish etc).

Comment: thanks for your inputs. This is not solving the issue. 

Can you please let me know what all steps I need to take so that www.mysite.com servers from a website folder [mysite in this case] ?

what exact configuration should be in server.xml file for this?

Comment: @SfdcWorkhorse No, it solves your issue. You said that you have changed the port to 9001 - change it to port 80 instead.